# Magento Custom Block Methods Not Working

Tags: php, magento

I've created a custom module in Magento but the methods I have defined for my block are not working for some reason. I can create an instance of the block in a template and call the parent blocks methods but not the methods I have defined.

/app/code/local/MyCompany/Morecategories/Block/List.php

```
<?php
class MyCompany_Morecategories_Block_List extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

  public function getMoreCategories() {
    return 'More categories';
  }
}
```

Then in my template file, if I run `$this->getMoreCategories()` it returns null.

I've tried running `get_class($this)`, and it returns `MyCompany_Morecategories_Block_List`.

I've also run `get_class_methods($this)` but it only returned the parent blocks methods.

I can't imagine why my methods are not working.

Comment: If you have the compilation enabled, disable it. (you can enable it later again).

Comment: The compiler is disabled already